# How to save two imageviews in one image view after drawing in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6

** i have two image views one for background and one for foreground and i  am drawing on foreground imageview.for the erase functionality i am doing this because i do not want to erase background image at the time of erase.its doing fine.now i want to save that image(background + foreground) and i need to sand that by mail.it is possible? **

```
    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (doodlemode==YES){

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];


    // calculate mid point
    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageDoodle.frame.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


     [imgView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageDoodle.frame.size.width,      

     imageDoodle.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);

    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

    [imgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    //this is for erase
    if(IsErase)
    {
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context,kCGBlendModeClear);
    }
    //make a strok color
    else
    {
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), redvalue, greenvalue, bluevalue,  

    1.0);
    }

    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 8.0);
    //size of stroke

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());


    imgView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    }

 }
   -(IBAction)sharePrint{
    //Compose email with activity sheet attached

     MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

     picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [UIImage imageNamed:@"feedback.png"]]];

    *//here i nedd to sand that. Image  how can i?*

     NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgView.image);

    [picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"shared.png"];

     //Show Mail view with composed email

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void) someMethod {
    UIImage *newImage = [self captureScreen];
    IBbtn1.hidden = FALSE;
    IBbtn2.hidden = FALSE;
}

- (UIImage *) captureScreen { 

    IBbtn1.hidden = TRUE;
    IBbtn2.hidden = TRUE;

    CGRect rect = [wrapperView bounds]; 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size); 
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    [wrapperView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
    return img; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture view which is having background and foreground image and store it as a sinalge image and can mail that captured image.

Comment: once you edit both, you can capture that view (which is having foreground and background image) and store it as a image

Comment: how can i capture that view give me one example.

Comment: Let's say, you have a view having your foreground and background view inside it, named wrapperView. Use following function to convert your view into image:

Comment: - (UIImage *) captureScreen {
    CGRect rect = [wrapperView bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [wrapperView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}

This function will return you an image which you can email

Comment: ok thanx you solved my problem but by this it capture all view and in my view i have some button also and i dont want capture that buttons.For that what can i do

Comment: just hide those buttons inside captureScreen method and once you captured your view, make hidden false for all those buttons.

Comment: check detail answer as new my new answer